# Serial device sends one character at a time

Tags: linux, tty, serial-port

I have an ACCESS IO serial card. I use the stock Linux serial driver. However, when I write data to the serial port, the output on the line as measured with an oscilloscope is one character at a time with gaps - i.e. <char>[gap]<char>[gap]<char>..., as opposed to a continuous stream - i.e. <char><char><char>....

What is the reason for this behavior?
Is there some settings in the port or the chip that sets this?

Comment: A serial port can only output one character at a time. Besides, what is the difference between "one character at a time" and "continuous stream"? Even a continuous stream consists of one character at a time. In other words, please elaborate.

Comment: @berndbausch you are correct that a serial port can only output one character at a time. However, when I put a scope on the line I see <char>[gap]<char>[gap]. What I want to see - <char>char><char>. The difference - I have timing requirements for my receiver and those extra gaps mess it up.

Comment: You may want to add this clarification to the question. Perhaps also other details e.g. how you configured the card or the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Our UART is based on the [Pericom PI7C9X7958ANBE](https://datasheet.octopart.com/PI7C9X7958ANBE-Pericom-datasheet-11898032.pdf) chip. For some reason the regular Linux kernel driver doesn't have support for this specific chip and thus doesn't recognize it. As a result it doesn't enable enhanced modes with hardware FIFOs.